# Using ModelBuilder to count number of times pixel has value higher than zero for more than three consecutive rasters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I am quite new to the iterators within ModelBuilder. I have 2500 rasters representing a temperature in a region of Norway on a given day at 1 km resolution. I am interested in when the temperature is above freezing for three consecutive days (as then a layer of ice forms on top of the snow).

The raster files are in the format TM_YYYY_MM_DD. I have been trying to use Calculate field to add a value of either 1 or 2 onto the DD value, however this doesn't work since I don't have the files saved in a julian day format.

Is there a way where I can iterative through the folder and create one raster for each set of three temperature rasters where the pixel values have a value of 1 if the temperature was above zero for three days, and a value of 0 if it was below zero on one or more of these days?

Following on from this, is there a way I can count the number of these events per pixel?

Comment: When you say you have 2,500 rasters, are these 2,500 rasters covering exactly the same area and represent a single day? So you have approximately 7 years worth of data? Or are these many rasters  covering different areas of Norway and representing different ranges of dates? Please amend your question with this information and may be some images?

Comment: Yes the rasters cover exactly the same area (Hardangervidda) and are every day from November to the end of March between 2000 and 2016. I can add some example data if it helps? I guess it could be useful to convert to Julian days first?

Thanks for the help!

Ben